# Logical bits operators (C)

Tags: c

Logical bits operators what are used for? I heard I can test if a number is odd or not by reading the last bit. I don't have any idea. I need a practical example. Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Is it too hard to read it in a book or google the first example? Once you get the concept of operators, then you can understand the usage whether even odd or any other.

Comment: "last bit" is a little ambiguous. It's typically called the least significant bit, or lsb.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra <<< Before programming

Comment: @user2956608 will you be back on #omnimaga? It's ok if you don't want to, of course.

Answer (score 2):

If the number is odd, its last digit (binary) is 1. For instance:

```
5 ~  00000101
31 ~ 00011111
but 8 ~ 00001000
```

So, if you AND it (bit by bit) with 1, which is

```
1 ~ 00000...01
```

You get 1 as a result if the number is odd (i.e. its last digit is 1).

```
5 ~ 00000101
1 ~ 00000001
-------------
    00000001 => odd
```

Another usage would be storing multiple flags in one variable, cryptography etc. etc. There are really many of them.

Answer (score 0):

Usually numbers which are having their LSB bit as `1` are odd. So you can just check it using bitwise AND operator whether last LSB bit is set or not, if yes it is Odd number.

```
if((num & 1) == 1); // Its an odd number
```

However , you cannot mix logical operators with bitwise operators. They are different in as,

1. We have logical operators to do boolean logic (on boolean values).
2. We have bitwise operators to do bitwise logic (on integer values).

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common applications of binary operations are bitfields. If you need, for example, to know a state which has 2 possible values, instead of using an array of chars or bools, that needs 1 byte for each state, you may use the same array, but you may use every bit to retain the state of an object, an so using 8 times less memory. Also, you may use binary operations for flagging some errors, for example. In this case it's very easy both to pass them or, using some operators, to find errors that occured in multiple places (binary and) or to bring toghether errors from multiple sources (binary or). Also, by using binary xor you can find errors that occured in one place, but not in the other.
Note: you can replace 'errors' with many other things.